# Database connection in yii with hive database

Tags: php, yii, hive

Does anyone know how to connect a hive database to YII framework?For the ODBC connection, YII's documentation provides the following code. But it doesn't work.

```
array(
    ......
    'components'=>array(
        ......
        'db'=>array(
            'class'=>'CDbConnection',
            'connectionString'=>'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb',
            'username'=>'root',
            'password'=>'password',
            'emulatePrepare'=>true,  // needed by some MySQL installations
        ),
    ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

for ODBC you could use  http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/it/database.dao

> When using ODBC, its connection string (DSN) doesn't indicate uniquely
>   what database type is being used (MySQL, MS SQL Server, etc.). Thus
>   it's not able to automatically detect needed DBMS specific classes
>   (CMysqlSchema, CMssqlSchema and so forth).
>
> That's why you have to use $driverName property of the CDbConnection class to disambiguate that:

```
array(
  ......
  'components'=>array(
    ......
    'db'=>array(
        'class'=>'CDbConnection'
        'driverName'=>'mysql',
        'connectionString'=>'odbc:Driver={MySQL};Server=127.0.0.1;Database=test',
        'username'=>'',
        'password'=>'',
    ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: I tried this also,but it doesn't establish the connection

Comment: Have you setted  the proper database, username and pasword ?